# What is the Origin (the start point when learning was started) of an Area Description File in Tango Service

Tags: android, google-project-tango

[AreaLearning Documentation](https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/area-learning) says that after Localization in an ADF (Area Description File) the Tango Services knows exactly where the Device is w.r.t ADF's Origin (the start point when learning was started).

I'm creating an Indoor map application using Tango in Unity3D & I want to align the ADF's Origin with Unity's World Space Origin(0,0,0); so that the localized position exactly matches with the Map.

Any help please. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working in Tango Java API but I think my answer will help you.

For me, I succeeded in place a cube to the origin in the scene of camera.

[screen shot of the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlZl7.jpg)

In this figure, the origin 1 is the place where I began my localization and origin 2 is where the exploration began.

In fact, I've done this:
1.Create a renderer for the scene (example in Java Augmented Reality)
2.register a callback that: first set up scene camera projection to match the camera then get the frame pose for the renderer
3.Update the position of the cube (fix 0, 0, 0 for the origin 1)(Area learning - first pair)

For your question, you need to align the coordinate system of camera used in Unity3D and Tango Service.

Hope that my answer help.

Comment: Thanks @danielwen it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This method should help you. You can specify the Unity engine, BaseFrame and TargetFrame. Then you get the Pose you need.

https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/support/reference/TangoSupport.html#getPoseAtTime-double-int-int-int-int-